# Copy and paste between remote sessions using Remmina

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

In the past, I have been able to copy and paste text between Windows and Linux remote desktop sessions.

Now for some reason, I cannot do this. I would like to regain this functionality, how might I do that?

I am using Remmina for my remote desktop connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I was reading the README in the new source code. I got to the line were it says: install dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cmake intltool   libgtk-3-dev libssh-dev libavahi-ui-gtk3-dev libvte-2.90-dev libxkbfile-dev 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
cmake is already the newest version.

Suggested packages:
  autoconf2.13 autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc libtool
  libgtk-3-doc libssh-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake autotools-dev intltool libatk-bridge2.0-dev
  libavahi-client-dev libavahi-common-dev libavahi-glib-dev libavahi-ui-gtk3-0
  libavahi-ui-gtk3-dev libdbus-1-dev libgtk-3-dev libssh-dev libssl-dev
  libssl-doc libvte-2.90-dev libvte-2.90-doc libwayland-dev libxkbcommon-dev
  libxkbfile-dev
0 upgraded, 20 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,839 kB of archives.
After this operation, 28.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

Once I installed that, I tested the old version I am currently using, Remmina 0.9.99.1
runs, (as it did) but copy paste functionality has resumed.

The source for version 1 still failed to compile, that's a bummer, but as long as i can copy and paste in a relatively new version, I'm ok with this solution. Try it if you like.

Comment: Package libvte-2.90-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libvte-2.90-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: For me (Linux Mint 18.03) `libvte-dev` did the trick.

Answer (score 12):

It's not a solution, but if you don't have time to install anything, reboot, or investigate what's going on:

**Close session, restart Remmina and open session again.**

It worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too, odd...

Comment: did not work for me :(

Comment: Rebooting remote server worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I too am experiencing this in Ubuntu 15.04. For now, all I can do is direct you to the bug I reported:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1439478

**Update:** I ultimately solved this by installing a newer version of Remmina, this way:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install remmina remmina-plugin-rdp
```

After doing this, reboot.

Comment: Cool, I reported it. hey there is a new version. Ill try that. Or maybe Ill go back to an older version. https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/downloads

Comment: I also had to manually upgrade `libfreerdp-plugins-standard`; for some reason the dependencies weren't properly set in the packages: `sudo apt-get install libfreerdp-plugins-standard`

Comment: Copy pasting text to and from host Ubuntu and remote Windows is working with RDP. But I cannot copy paste image from host Ubuntu to Office running on remote Windows. Does this need some more configuration / installation?

Comment: This still worked for me on 22.04!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct solution for the question but a work around I use I've shared a folder between host computer and remote server using [SambaShare](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#1-overview) there I keep a text file always open at both places basically to copy anything from one another. If nothing works this maybe a good one instead of typing manually.

Comment: This is something I've had to do when connecting to some Windows Server instances through Remmina. It's ugly, but it works in a pinch ...

Answer (score 0):

When a new connection is being created in REMMINA, selecting the RDP protocol, a shared folder can be enabled, during configuration, in this way the remote computer can view it as a network drive and files can be copied and pasted from this unit shared, no need to install additional software.

I hope this information is useful.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVqfu.png)

Comment: the example looks to me like an image with only white pixels in it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above suggestions have worked for me. But feeding off @Cruguer's answer, I found it useful to

1. enable a shared drive in Remmina (option is in Basic tab, under Domain text box), then
2. Install Shutter app and
3. in Shutter's preferences (Edit -> Preferences -> Save -> Directory) set it to automatically save screenshots to that same directory.