# copy paste between remote sessions remmina in ubuntu 20.04 LT

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina, copy-and-paste

in the past, i have been able to copy and paste text  windows remote desktop sessions. Now for some reason, I cannot do this. I would like to regain this functionality, how might i do that? I am using remmina version 1.4.7 for my remote desktop connection.

I have tried using below

```
sudo apt-get install cmake intltool   libgtk-3-dev libssh-dev libavahi-ui-gtk3-dev libvte-2.91-dev libxkbfile-dev
```

but my issue has not been solved yet

Comment: Wondering if you’ve seen the following?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/601204/copy-paste-between-remote-sessions-remmina

Comment: I followed that link before posting this

Answer (score 1):

https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/issues/243 says that shares show up using Remmina when you also enable sound redirection. To recap, here is what you have to do:

```
Create a Remmina RDP connection to the windows machine
Edit that connection.
Under the Basic tab Choose a share folder
In Advanced tab, change sound to local. Save it and connect
```

Then the shared folder appears in My computer in windows.
(If it does not appear, trying clicking Refresh).